# What import system should I use when I want to run my application both 'from source' and from installing with setuptools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package

Consider this application:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── program
│   ├── apple.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── nonfruit.py
│   ├── pear.py
│   ├── strawberry.py
│   └── vegetables
│       ├── carrot.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── lettuce.py
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

`__main__.py` is the file that users should run to use my program. I am distributing my program via PyPI and so I want to be able to install it via pip as well. Because of that, I created a `setup.py` file with an entry point:

```
entry_points = {
      'console_scripts': ['pg=program.__main__:main']}
```

The problem I'm facing is that there are several imports in my program, and these result in the situation that my program does run 'locally' (by executing `python ./__main__.py`, but not from installation (by running `pg`). Or, depending on the way I import it, the other way around.

`__main__.py` imports `nonfruit.py`:

```
from nonfruit import Nonfruit
```

`nonfruit.py` imports `vegetables/carrot.py`:

```
import vegetables.carrot
ca = vegetables.carrot.Carrot()
```

I would like to hear some advice in structuring my project regarding imports, so that it runs both locally and from setuptools installation. For example, should I use absolute imports or relative imports? And should I use `from X import Y` or `import X.Y`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on [Jan-Philip Gehrcke's website](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/).

The instructions are written for use with Python 3, but I applied it to Python 2.7 with success. The problem I was having originated from my directory becoming a package. Jan advices to create one file to run it from source (`bootstrap-runner.py`) and one file to run it from installation (`bootstrap/__main__.py`). Furthermore, he advices to use explicit relative imports:

```
from .X import Y
```

This will probably be a good guideline in the next applications I'm writing.